# Example of [NSDictionary getObjects:andKeys:]

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, arrays, nsdictionary

I couldn't find a working example of the method `[NSDictionary getObjects:andKeys:]`. The only [example](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg24959.html) I could find, doesn't compile. I provided the errors/warnings here in case someone is searching for them.

The reason I was confused is because most methods on NSDictionary return an `NSArray`. However, in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/getObjects:andKeys:) it states that the out variables of this method are returned as C arrays.

Here are the error messages/warnings you might get if you follow the linked example:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = ...;

id objects[]; // Error: Array size missing in 'objects'
id keys[]; // Error: Array size missing in 'keys'

[myDictionary getObjects:&objects andKeys:&keys];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  id obj = objects[i];
  id key = keys[i];
}
```

.

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = ...;

NSInteger count = [myDictionary count];
id objects[count];
id keys[count];
[myDictionary getObjects:&objects andKeys:&keys]; // Warning: Passing argument 1 of 'getObjects:andKeys:' from incompatible pointer type.

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  id obj = objects[i];
  id key = keys[i];
}
```

I'll provide a working solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the correct way to use this method:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"A", @"2", @"B", nil];

NSInteger count = [myDictionary count];
id objects[count];
id keys[count];
[myDictionary getObjects:objects andKeys:keys];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  id obj = objects[i];
  id key = keys[i];
  NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", obj, key);
}
```

Comment: do i need to release obj and key ?

Comment: Just in case anyones wondering why you dont need to release anything (this was a thing that killed me in early development) it's because nothing was alloc'd. No memory allocated = no memory needed to be released. Obvious but if i'd seen this a few months ago i'd have no idea why you wouldn't use release :)

Comment: With ARC on this code generates "Sending '__strong id *' to parameter of type '__unsafe_unretained id *' changes retain/release properties of pointer.

Answer (score 8):

Under ARC the solution needs to be modified as follows (__unsafe_unretained added to the array definitions):

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"A", @"2", @"B", nil];

NSInteger count = [myDictionary count];
id __unsafe_unretained objects[count];
id __unsafe_unretained keys[count];
[myDictionary getObjects:objects andKeys:keys];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  id obj = objects[i];
  id key = keys[i];
  NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", obj, key);
}
```