# What's the meaning of return by reference C array?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, convention

I used `-[NSDictionary getObjects:andKeys:]` method first time, and I discovered there's no policy on description should I `free` the memory or not. I think * Returns by reference C arrays* means it's just a reference to internal memory block, so I shouldn't `free` them, but it is not sure. Should I `free` them?

And I think there're some conventions about this. What are the convention or where can I find the conventions or rules about C memory management on Objective-C/Cocoa? (of course, I know Objective-C level conventions but I mean case of using C-level objects)

Comment: This prior question might clear things up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894093/example-of-nsdictionary-getobjectsandkeys

Comment: Think you should read about memory management too: http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not release the objects or keys. They will be released when the dictionary is released. While this call may be useful in some situations, in general I would try sticking to other methods if you want to iterate all of the items in a dictionary, such as -enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock or -allKeys.